# derivative of sum of vectors

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis, partial-derivative

suppose i need to make the partial derivative of this vector function $f(\vec{a},\vec{b})=\frac{1}{| \vec{a}+\vec{b}|}$ respect to $\vec{a}$:

$\frac{\partial }{\partial \vec{a}} f(\vec{a},\vec{b})$,

this should be equal to:

$-\frac{1}{| \vec{a}+\vec{b}|^3}(\vec{a}+\vec{b})$,

is the result correct? Or something like:

$-\frac{\hat{a}}{| \vec{a}+\vec{b}|^2}$

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? What have you tried? What is the definition of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\vec a}$ in terms of limits?

Answer (score 0):

Write out the function fully. If $a=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$, then $$f(\vec a,\vec b) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i + b_i)^2}}.$$

Now calculate $\frac{df}{da_i}$ for each $i$.

Comment: I don't have the component of the vector, this is the reason because i try to make the derivative as the one defined by the law of simple derivative: $A=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{f(x)}=-\frac{1}{f(x)^2}f'(x)$, now remember that $x$ is a vector I need to define also the direction of the vector using the definition of unit vector, such as: $\overrightarrow{A}=A\frac{\overrightarrow{x}}{|x|}$ and from this calculation I found the result I present in the question.